# Sitecore: Error when removing link

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.5

We have a Sitecore 7.5 site where I'm trying to remove some items, but getting an error when trying to remove the links. All the errors are in reference to one of our Rendering Parameter templates. The exception is: EditingNotAllowedException. The offending item is the __Standard Values on a Rendering Paramater template. It says that it "is not in editing mode" I'm not sure why Sitecore would need to edit a __Standard Value item under a template when remove a link, but hey I'm new to Sitecore.

Each of the items we're trying to delete contain the component that uses that Rendering Parameter template.

Another interesting fact is that each of these items also contain a link to themselves.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why your items contain a link to themselves?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you are trying to delete an item that  is being used as the datasource of another item, in this case standard values item of the parameters template. If you clear out the datasource you should be able to delete the item. You can find all links to an item by going to the "navigate" menu in content editor and clicking the "Links" ribbon button.